How to find strings in multiple lines of txt file then add all to new csv line
I have thousands of txt files that were converted from emails that included a "Contact Us" form. I need to find/select strings in the second "column", but the number of lines to start each email are variable. It seems that the columns are tab delimited. To boot, the last field in the contact form spans multiple lines and some of the emails have pipe symbols "|" that seem to have been created since I used html2text to convert these to txt files. How can I extract the values of the "First Name", "Last Name", and "Long Text" fields? Ultimately these will be added as a new line in a csv.
 variable number of lines at start of email
 ...
 ..
 |First Name  [tab] Bob          |                               
 |Last Name   [tab] Jones        |                                      
 (more lines like above)                                               
 |Long Text   [tab] laksjdflkjasl|  
                   fasgafg asdfj |
                     gsfg  asdgfa|
                   gsg ergsdfgre | 

Using awk, below is not very effective, probably because of the space in First Name and Last Name but putting this in quotes did not work
awk -F'First Name|Last Name' '{print $2}' 1.txt
And I am really not sure how to approach the Long Text field as below only prints one line and not all the text that I need
awk -F'Long Text' '{print $2}' 1.txt
It seems using awk with tab field separator could be possible but I have not gotten very far trying that.
Sample HTML reformatted with hxnormalize:
<html>
  <body>
    <p> <mailer-daemon>  </mailer-daemon>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"
  xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml"
  xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
  xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
  xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word">
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=us-ascii" http-equiv=Content-Type
      >
    <meta content="Microsoft Word 15 (filtered medium)" name=Generator
      ><!--[if !mso]><style>v\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
o\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
w\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
.shape {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
</style><![endif]-->

    <title>Contact Us - Form Submission</title>

    <style><!--
/* Font Definitions */
@font-face
    {font-family:"Cambria Math";
    panose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:Calibri;
    panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;}
/* Style Definitions */
p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
    {margin:0in;
    font-size:11.0pt;
    font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;}
a:link, span.MsoHyperlink
    {mso-style-priority:99;
    color:blue;
    text-decoration:underline;}
span.EmailStyle19
    {mso-style-type:personal-reply;
    font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;
    color:windowtext;}
.MsoChpDefault
    {mso-style-type:export-only;
    font-size:10.0pt;}
@page WordSection1
    {size:8.5in 11.0in;
    margin:1.0in 1.0in 1.0in 1.0in;}
div.WordSection1
    {page:WordSection1;}
--></style><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<o:shapedefaults v:ext="edit" spidmax="1026" />
</xml><![endif]-->
<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<o:shapelayout v:ext="edit">
<o:idmap v:ext="edit" data="1" />
</o:shapelayout></xml><![endif]-->

  <body lang=EN-US link=blue style="word-wrap:break-word" vlink=purple
    >
    <div class=WordSection1>
      <p class=MsoNormal> <o:p></o:p>

      <p class=MsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p>

      <p class=MsoNormal
        style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto"
        ><span style="color:white;background:red"> </span><o:p></o:p
        >

      <div>
        <table border=1 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0
          class=MsoNormalTable
          style="width:487.5pt;border:solid #CCCCCC 2.25pt" width=650>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td
                style="border:none;padding:11.25pt 11.25pt 11.25pt 11.25pt"
                valign=top>
                <p class=MsoNormal><a
                  href="https://protect-us.mimecast.com/s/XqoHCmZ9ZBCWglGUGeKYC?domain=alliancepackaging.net"
                  target="_blank"><span
                  style="font-size:10.5pt;text-decoration:none"><img
                  border=0 height=31 id="_x0000_i1028"
                  src="https://www.alliancepackaging.net/graphics/logo.png"
                  style="width:3.4166in;height:.3229in" width=328
                  ></span></a><span
                  style="font-size:10.5pt;color:#666666"><o:p></o:p
                  ></span>

              <td
                style="border:none;padding:11.25pt 11.25pt 11.25pt 11.25pt"
                valign=top>
                <p align=right class=MsoNormal style="text-align:right"
                  ><span style="font-size:10.5pt;color:#666666"> <o:p></o:p></span>

            <tr>
              <td colspan=2
                style="border:none;padding:11.25pt 11.25pt 11.25pt 11.25pt"
                >
                <p class=MsoNormal style="margin-bottom:12.0pt"><span
                  style="font-size:10.5pt;color:#666666"><br>
                  </span><b><span
                  style="font-size:15.0pt;color:black"> </span></b
                  ><span style="font-size:10.5pt;color:#666666"> <o:p
                  ></o:p></span>

            <tr>
              <td colspan=2
                style="border:none;padding:11.25pt 11.25pt 11.25pt 11.25pt"
                >
                <p class=MsoNormal><span
                  style="font-size:10.5pt;color:#666666">  <o:p></o:p></span>

                <div align=center class=MsoNormal
                  style="text-align:center"><span
                  style="font-size:10.5pt;color:#666666"></span>
                  <hr align=center noshade size=2 style="color:#CCCCCC"
                    width="100%">
                </div>

            <tr>
              <td colspan=2
                style="border:none;padding:11.25pt 11.25pt 11.25pt 11.25pt"
                >
                <table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0
                  class=MsoNormalTable style="width:100.0%"
                  width="100%">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td
                        style="width:30.0%;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt"
                        valign=top width="30%">
                        <p class=MsoNormal><b><span
                          style="font-size:10.5pt;color:#666666">First
                          Name<o:p></o:p></span></b>

                      <td
                        style="width:70.0%;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt"
                        valign=top width="70%">
                        <p class=MsoNormal><span
                          style="font-size:10.5pt;color:#666666"
                          >Bob<o:p></o:p></span>

                    <tr>
                      <td
                        style="width:30.0%;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt"
                        valign=top width="30%">
                        <p class=MsoNormal><b><span
                          style="font-size:10.5pt;color:#666666">Last
                          Name<o:p></o:p></span></b>

                      <td
                        style="width:70.0%;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt"
                        valign=top width="70%">
                        <p class=MsoNormal><span
                          style="font-size:10.5pt;color:#666666"
                          >Jones<o:p></o:p></span>

                    <tr>
                      <td
                        style="width:30.0%;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt"
                        valign=top width="30%">
                        <p class=MsoNormal><b><span
                          style="font-size:10.5pt;color:#666666"
                          >Company Name<o:p></o:p></span></b>

                      <td
                        style="width:70.0%;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt"
                        valign=top width="70%">
                        <p class=MsoNormal><span
                          style="font-size:10.5pt;color:#666666">Business Inc.<o:p></o:p></span>

                    <tr>
                      <td
                        style="width:30.0%;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt"
                        valign=top width="30%">
                        <p class=MsoNormal><b><span
                          style="font-size:10.5pt;color:#666666"
                          >Company Address<o:p></o:p></span></b>

                      <td
                        style="width:70.0%;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt"
                        valign=top width="70%">
                        <p class=MsoNormal><span
                          style="font-size:10.5pt;color:#666666"
                          >123<o:p></o:p></span>

                    <tr>
                      <td
                        style="width:30.0%;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt"
                        valign=top width="30%">
                        <p class=MsoNormal><b><span
                          style="font-size:10.5pt;color:#666666"
                          >City<o:p></o:p></span></b>

                      <td
                        style="width:70.0%;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt"
                        valign=top width="70%">
                        <p class=MsoNormal><span
                          style="font-size:10.5pt;color:#666666"
                          >New York<o:p></o:p></span>

                    <tr>
                      <td
                        style="width:30.0%;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt"
                        valign=top width="30%">
                        <p class=MsoNormal><b><span
                          style="font-size:10.5pt;color:#666666"
                          >State<o:p></o:p></span></b>

                      <td
                        style="width:70.0%;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt"
                        valign=top width="70%">
                        <p class=MsoNormal><span
                          style="font-size:10.5pt;color:#666666"
                          >New York<o:p></o:p></span>

                    <tr>
                      <td
                        style="width:30.0%;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt"
                        valign=top width="30%">
                        <p class=MsoNormal><b><span
                          style="font-size:10.5pt;color:#666666">Phone
                          Number<o:p></o:p></span></b>

                      <td
                        style="width:70.0%;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt"
                        valign=top width="70%">
                        <p class=MsoNormal><span
                          style="font-size:10.5pt;color:#666666"
                          >1234567890<o:p></o:p></span>

                    <tr>
                      <td
                        style="width:30.0%;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt"
                        valign=top width="30%">
                        <p class=MsoNormal><b><span
                          style="font-size:10.5pt;color:#666666">Email
                          Address<o:p></o:p></span></b>

                      <td
                        style="width:70.0%;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt"
                        valign=top width="70%">
                        <p class=MsoNormal><span
                          style="font-size:10.5pt;color:#666666"><a
                          href="mailto:user@mail.com"
                          >user@mail.com</a><o:p></o:p
                          ></span>

                      <td
                        style="width:30.0%;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt"
                        valign=top width="30%">
                        <p class=MsoNormal><b><span
                          style="font-size:10.5pt;color:#666666"
                          >Paragraph Text<o:p></o:p></span></b>

                      <td
                        style="width:70.0%;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt"
                        valign=top width="70%">
                        <p class=MsoNormal><span
                          style="font-size:10.5pt;color:#666666">Hi,
                          asdfasdf asdfasdfasdf asdfasdfasdf
                          asdfasdf asdfasdfasdf asdfasdfasdf 
                          asdf<o:p></o:p></span>


                    <tr>
                      <td
                        style="width:30.0%;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt"
                        valign=top width="30%">
                        <p class=MsoNormal><b><span
                          style="font-size:10.5pt;color:#666666"
                          >Name<o:p></o:p></span></b>

                      <td
                        style="width:70.0%;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt"
                        valign=top width="70%">

                    <tr>
                      <td
                        style="width:30.0%;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt"
                        valign=top width="30%">
                        <p class=MsoNormal><b><span
                          style="font-size:10.5pt;color:#666666"
                          >E-mail<o:p></o:p></span></b>

                      <td
                        style="width:70.0%;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt"
                        valign=top width="70%">
                        <p class=MsoNormal><span
                          style="font-size:10.5pt;color:#A1A1A1"
                          >(field not answered)</span><span
                          style="font-size:10.5pt;color:#666666"><o:p
                          ></o:p></span>

                    <tr>
                      <td
                        style="width:30.0%;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt"
                        valign=top width="30%">
                        <p class=MsoNormal><b><span
                          style="font-size:10.5pt;color:#666666"
                          >E-mail<o:p></o:p></span></b>

                      <td
                        style="width:70.0%;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt"
                        valign=top width="70%">
                        <p class=MsoNormal><span
                          style="font-size:10.5pt;color:#A1A1A1"
                          >(field not answered)</span><span
                          style="font-size:10.5pt;color:#666666"><o:p
                          ></o:p></span>

                    <tr>
                      <td
                        style="width:30.0%;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt"
                        valign=top width="30%">
                        <p class=MsoNormal><b><span
                          style="font-size:10.5pt;color:#666666"
                          >E-mail<o:p></o:p></span></b>

                      <td
                        style="width:70.0%;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt"
                        valign=top width="70%">
                        <p class=MsoNormal><span
                          style="font-size:10.5pt;color:#A1A1A1"
                          >(field not answered)</span><span
                          style="font-size:10.5pt;color:#666666"><o:p
                          ></o:p></span>

                    <tr>
                      <td
                        style="width:30.0%;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt"
                        valign=top width="30%">
                        <p class=MsoNormal><b><span
                          style="font-size:10.5pt;color:#666666"
                          >E-mail<o:p></o:p></span></b>

                      <td
                        style="width:70.0%;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt"
                        valign=top width="70%">
                        <p class=MsoNormal><span
                          style="font-size:10.5pt;color:#A1A1A1"
                          >(field not answered)</span><span
                          style="font-size:10.5pt;color:#666666"><o:p
                          ></o:p></span>

                    <tr>
                      <td
                        style="width:30.0%;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt"
                        valign=top width="30%">
                        <p class=MsoNormal><b><span
                          style="font-size:10.5pt;color:#666666"
                          >E-mail<o:p></o:p></span></b>

                      <td
                        style="width:70.0%;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt"
                        valign=top width="70%">
                        <p class=MsoNormal><span
                          style="font-size:10.5pt;color:#A1A1A1"
                          >(field not answered)</span><span
                          style="font-size:10.5pt;color:#666666"><o:p
                          ></o:p></span>

                    <tr>
                      <td
                        style="width:30.0%;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt"
                        valign=top width="30%">
                        <p class=MsoNormal><b><span
                          style="font-size:10.5pt;color:#666666"
                          >E-mail<o:p></o:p></span></b>

                      <td
                        style="width:70.0%;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt"
                        valign=top width="70%">
                        <p class=MsoNormal><span
                          style="font-size:10.5pt;color:#A1A1A1"
                          >(field not answered)</span><span
                          style="font-size:10.5pt;color:#666666"><o:p
                          ></o:p></span>

                    <tr>
                      <td colspan=2
                        style="padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt">
                        <p class=MsoNormal><span
                          style="font-size:10.5pt;color:#666666"
                          >&nbsp;<o:p></o:p></span>

                    <tr>
                      <td
                        style="width:30.0%;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt"
                        valign=top width="30%">

                      <td
                        style="width:70.0%;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt"
                        valign=top width="70%">
                </table>

            <tr>
              <td colspan=2
                style="border:none;padding:11.25pt 11.25pt 11.25pt 11.25pt"
                >
                <div align=center class=MsoNormal
                  style="text-align:center"><span
                  style="font-size:10.5pt;color:#666666"></span>
                  <hr align=center noshade size=2 style="color:#CCCCCC"
                    width="100%">
                </div>

            <tr>
              <td colspan=2
                style="border:none;padding:11.25pt 11.25pt 11.25pt 11.25pt"
                >
                <p class=MsoNormal><span
                  style="font-size:7.5pt;color:#666666">Please do not
                  reply to this email. This mailbox is not monitored
                  and will not receive a response.</span><span
                  style="font-size:10.5pt;color:#666666"> <o:p></o:p
                  ></span>
        </table>

        <p class=MsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p>
      </div>
    </div>

<html>
  <body>
    <p>----boundary-LibPST-iamunique-2056507128_-_---


Do you still have the original html files?

@Shawn yes, why?

Often easier to extract the desired information from a structured data format like HTML. Add an example file to the question?

What is the expected outcome, if those "lines at the start of the mail" also happen to contain tabs and pipe characters? How are you going to disambiguate them from the "real" data you are interested in?

Posting sample input without the associated expected output isn't very useful, especially when it's lengthy like that large block of html in the question, as it doesn't demonstrate how you want that input transformed into the output and we can't copy/paste it to test that a potential solution can transform the posted sample input correctly without having the associated expected output to compare it against.

And an ugly version that works on what you showed us ...
cat t.awk
$1~/(First|Last) Name/{
  gsub(/^ /,"",$2)
  gsub(/ *[|] *$/,"",$2)
  print $2
} 
/Long Text/,!/./{
  if(NF==2){
    gsub(/^ /,"",$2)
    gsub(/ *[|] *$/,"",$2)
    print $2
    }
  else{
    gsub(/^ */,"",$1)
    gsub(/ *[|] *$/,"",$1)
    print $1
  }

Invoke with
awk -F'\t' -f t.awk extract 
Bob
Jones
laksjdflkjasl
fasgafg asdfj
gsfg  asdgfa
gsg ergsdfgre


Since you didn't give a sample of the desired output but mentioned CSV...
cat t.awk 
$1~/(First|Last) Name/{
  gsub(/^ /,"",$2)
  gsub(/ *[|] *$/,"",$2)
  printf "%s,", $2
} 
/Long Text/,!/./{
  if(NF==2){
    gsub(/^ /,"",$2);
    gsub(/ *[|] *$/,"",$2);
    printf "%s,", $2
    }
  else{
    gsub(/^ */,"",$1);
    gsub(/ *[|] *$/,"",$1);
    printf "%s", $1
  }
}

which then gives you:
awk -F'\t' -f t.awk extract 
Bob,Jones,laksjdflkjasl,fasgafg asdfjgsfg  asdgfagsg ergsdfgre


With Mike Farah's yq, it seems to be:
hxclean in.html |
hxselect table table p span |
yq -p xml -o csv '[ .span[]."+content" ] | [ .[1],.[3],.[17] ]'

Running on your sample html gives:
Bob,Jones,"Hi,
                          asdfasdf asdfasdfasdf asdfasdfasdf
                          asdfasdf asdfasdfasdf asdfasdfasdf 
                          asdf"

(Perhaps don't pre-process with hxnormalize.)

You didn't show any expected output, so here's how to do what you asked for:

extract the values of the "First Name", "Last Name", and "Long Text" fields

using any POSIX awk and you can figure out how to tweak the prt() function to change the output to whatever final format you like:
$ cat tst.awk
sub(/^ \|/,"") {
    if ( inVal ) {
        sub(/\|[^|]*$/,"",val)
        prt()
        val = ""
        inVal = 0
    }
    if ( match($0, /^((First|Last) Name|Long Text)[[:space:]]/) ) {
        tag = substr($0,1,RLENGTH-1)
        val = substr($0,RLENGTH)
        inVal = 1
    }
    next
}
inVal { val = val ORS $0 }
END { prt() }

function prt() {
    print "tag:", tag
    print "val:", val
    print "#########"
}


$ awk -f tst.awk file
tag: First Name
val:   [tab] Bob
#########
tag: Last Name
val:    [tab] Jones
#########
tag: Long Text
val:    [tab] laksjdflkjasl|
                   fasgafg asdfj |
                     gsfg  asdgfa|
                   gsg ergsdfgre
#########

